# Concatenation strings in freemarker

Tags: freemarker, template-engine, string-concatenation

How can I concatenate strings in freemarker?

This doesn't work.

```
    <#function foo input>
<#local str="Hello ">
${str} = ${str} + ${" world"}

<#return str>
</#function>

${foo("a")}
```

Here is online evaluator: 
http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/

**Edit:** To make it clear I need to use it with variables, to be able write something like this.

```
public String sayHello() {return "Hello";}
public String sayWorld() {return "world"};
public String sayPeople() {return "people";}

public void main() { 
 String str = "";
 str += sayHello();
 str += "";
 str += sayWorld();
 str += "";
 str += sayPeople();

 return str;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like `<#return "Hello " + input + "!">`, or `<#return "Hello ${input}!">`. If you try to print to the output inside a `#function` (as opposed to inside a `#macro`), it will be ignored.

Edit: Analogously with the Java example added:

```
<#function concatDemo>
 <#local str = "">
 <#local str += sayHello()>
 <#local str += " ">
 <#local str += sayWorld()>
 <#local str += "!">
 <#return str>
</#function>

<#function sayHello><#return "Hello"></#function>
<#function sayWorld><#return "World"></#function>

${concatDemo()}
```

Comment: Thanks but you completely skipped the variable, which I need to use. Please see my edit.